# Google map is issue after deployed in production

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

**Found the issue:**

=========================================================================

> The issue is from the api key. After adding the api key, the google
>   map is working fine. I am not sure about that. But in many google
>   references, I have seen that google map api v3 doesn't require api key
>   but recommended. After including the api key, the issue has been
>   resolved.

=========================================================================

I have implemented in google map through angularjs directive. 
In local, the google map is working fine. After deployed the version, the same code is not working.

In initialize map itself, I am getting the following exception.

```
new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager
```

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since last month the key is required for new projects or domains, take a look at [Google Developers Blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html). More information you'll find in the [clickstorm Blog](https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/google-maps-api-nur-noch-mit-key/) (german).